# Can't setup AD FS with SimpleSAMLphp, where do I get the metadata?

Tags: adfs

I'm following this article to setup AD FS SSO with PHP: https://stratbeans.medium.com/how-to-integrate-active-directory-in-php-application-for-sso-22eb62b6b866

I've successfully setup nginx + php-fpm on Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm stuck here:

[image]

Where can I find the metadata on AD FS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD FS metadata XML is publicly accessible at the following URL: `https://<your ADFS hostname>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`

It appears you need to enter that URL.